# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when trying to run a bot command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

[Cont. of my last two posts]

After upgrading aiohttp and fixing the import issue with "main", I ran into another error while trying to run a command from the Discord bot. Is there any way to fix this?

```
Ignoring exception in command botcheck
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\Desktop\JerryBot\run.py", line 15, in botcheck
    await bot.say("I am up and running! {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention())
)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
ges\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Typ
eError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: `ctx.message.author.mention` is what type of object?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of the run.py code

Comment: Questions with typos are typically closed or deleted. By the way

Answer (score 0):

Just realized a typo was the issue. Oopsies..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, typos should be deleted (by clicking the `delete` button) since not many people will benefit from finding typographical error questions.